# Understanding theorem in Rudin’s Principles of Mathematical Analysis Theorem 9.21

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose  $\textbf{f}$ maps an open set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ into $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then $\textbf{f} \in C'(E)$ if and only if the partial derivatives $D_jf_i$ exist and are continuous on $E$ for $1\leq i \leq m ,1\leq i \leq n $.

This is theorem 9.21 of Rudin 3rd edition (page 219).

In the proof, for the converse part rudin proved the result only for $m=1$. How we can prove the converse part for $m>1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\textbf{f}=(f_1,...,f_m):E \to \mathbb R^m$ with $f_j: E \to \mathbb R$.

Then we have;

$\textbf{f} \in C^1(E, \mathbb R^m)  \iff f_1,...,f_m \in C^1(E, \mathbb R).$

Comment: How can we prove the result $\textbf{f}\in C'(E,\mathbb{R^m )}$ $\Longleftrightarrow f_1 ,...,f_m \in C'( E, \mathbb{R})$

Comment: Convergence in $ \mathbb R^m$ is coordinate wise convergence !

Comment: Sorry.I am not understanding the role of convergence in this part.can you please make it clear.